# Moving a HTML site to PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I currently run a site with 750 pages of .html webpages (yeah I know it was a stupid idea, but I'm a novice). I'm looking to move these to php. I don't really want to set up 750 individual 301 redirects and rewrite each page to .php

I've heard that I can use htaccess to this. Anyone know how?

A few additional questions -

1. Can I permanently redirect these links from html to php without losing my search engine rankings and
2. if I want to add php to each of the files (i.e. a php file menu (using the include command) to make the links quicker to update will this work? Because won't they still be html files?

Sorry for the stupid questions, but I'm still learning.

Comment: why you want to migrate to php? what is the usefulness in that, simply redirecting the files? You migrate in php if you create a site dynamic. with few pages you see many pages. But your idea is, having html site of 300 pages, want to move it in a php site, 300 pages redirected. not a good Idea

Comment: If you want to just redirect, apache can do. What will you move to/write to php then? Nothing left for php.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on a 750 page site - you must have put some work into that.

To collect your current list of pages use a tool called xenu to create an export into excel. You can then easily change the name the files to PHP in column b and create a .htaccees file.

However why would you want 750 php files? If you have lots of data pages, make it one page and suck in the HTML main content and reference one page. If you have a page called warehouse-depot-22-row-44.html then change that to show-warehouse-row.php?depot=22&row=44 and return that content only. This will significantly reduce your number of pages and to start using databases to render the content.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting you could use the Apache Module mod_rewrite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewriting to match a specific file name request with a regular expression and then decide where to redirect if matched

```
RewriteRule ^myname/?$  myname.php    [NC,L]
```

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the structure you have.
You want the user to access them in their natural location?

```
/public_html/folder1/file.php
user would access like
mydomain.com/folder1/file
```

or you want to map them differently?

Personally I think I would use a rewrite rule to map all requests to my /public_html/index.php and would map the requests from there using php (using include for instance). This gives great flexibility, plus you have a single point of entry for your application which is very beneficial since you can easily maintain control of the application flow.

The .htaccess would look like this

```
#
# Redirect all to index.php
#
RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

of course I place all my not directly accessible files (everything except index and css, js, images, etc) to a folder outside the public_html to ensure no user can ever access them directly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar (yet much much smaller) site that went through the same thing.

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

This will help redirect any visitors to your .html addresses to your .php addresses.

You hopefully have an IDE (I recommend Aptana), and you can use some of the find/change functions project-wide, and hopefully with some time and patience get your internal links from .html to .php.

But, I caution you a little bit - Perhaps it is time to look into a database based CMS, such as Wordpress or Drupal?